# Camel restlet only binds to localhost

Tags: apache-camel, restlet

I have a camel restlet application. The application exposes multiple http endpoints. Lately, I updated all camel components to 2.22.1 and added some other things. While all is still running fine, the application seems to be bound only to localhost:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:8082         0.0.0.0:0              ABHÖREN         7608
```

(netstat windows).

Could this have been caused by the update? How can I set the binding address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html
you should use restConfiguration like this 
restConfiguration().component("restlet").host("0.0.0.0");